# Publising some thing to facebook friends feeds

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish, facebook-javascript-sdk

Salam, Hi and Hello,

I am using FB.ui method of Facebook Javascript SDK and it says, "post to your wall", I want to publish story on facebook friend's wall or in feeds. So is it possible to post story on friends feeds other than your own wall? If yes then how? I doubt that it was only possible in depreciated libraries?

I am currently using following code:

```
   FB.ui({'method': 'stream.publish',
       'from':from_user_id,
       'display':'iframe',
     'attachment':attachment,
     'description': '',
     'message': message,
     'user_prompt_message': "Personailze Message",
     'action_links': [
                { text: 'AppName', href: canvasURL }
            ]
    },
    function(response){ 
       });
```

A Dialog is appearing but it says, "Post to Your Wall"
But What I want is that it say post to Your wall and Your Friends Home Page? as here:
http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development/

I followed this tutorial but it is still saying:  "Post to Your Wall"

So is there any clue? That How can I achieve the intended functionality? Waiting for your response.

thanks in advance

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post on any friends wall you have to add the friends id so it'll look like this

```
FB.ui(
            {
                method: 'feed',
                name: 'NAME',
                link: 'LINK OF THE WEBSITE OR PAGE',
                picture: 'IMAGE_URL IF YOU NEED IT',
                caption: 'Reference Documentation',
                description: "DESCRIPTION",
                to:FRIENDS_ID
            },
            function(response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                    alert('Post was published.');

                } else {
                    alert('Post was not published.');
                }
            }
        );
```